# send object as parameters into multipart-form

Tags: restsharp

I want to send and object ( application/xml ) into multipart-form.

```
This is the capture of request in java what goes right:
POST /OpenKM/services/rest/document/create HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary_1_1316797734_1423153602196
Authorization: Basic b2ttQWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
MIME-Version: 1.0
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_60
Host: localhost:8180
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

74
--Boundary_1_1316797734_1423153602196
**Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="doc"**


20c
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;&lt;document&gt;&lt;path&gt;/okm:root/myDoc.doc&lt;/path&gt;&lt;permissions&gt;0&lt;/permissions&gt;&lt;subscribed&gt;false&lt;/subscribed&gt;&lt;checkedOut&gt;false&lt;/checkedOut&gt;&lt;convertibleToDxf&gt;false&lt;/convertibleToDxf&gt;&lt;convertibleToPdf&gt;false&lt;/convertibleToPdf&gt;&lt;convertibleToSwf&gt;false&lt;/convertibleToSwf&gt;&lt;description&gt;&lt;/description&gt;&lt;locked&gt;false&lt;/locked&gt;&lt;signed&gt;false&lt;/signed&gt;&lt;/document&gt;
--Boundary_1_1316797734_1423153602196
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"

This is what I get from .net
POST /OpenKM/services/rest/document/create HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic b2ttQWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Accept: application/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/104.4.0.0
Host: localhost:8180
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------28947758029299
Content-Length: 24353
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

-------------------------------28947758029299
**Content-Disposition: form-data; name="doc"**

&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;&lt;document&gt;
  &lt;lastModified&gt;01/01/0001 0:00:00&lt;/lastModified&gt;
  &lt;locked&gt;false&lt;/locked&gt;
  &lt;checkedOut&gt;false&lt;/checkedOut&gt;
  &lt;signed&gt;false&lt;/signed&gt;
  &lt;convertibleToPdf&gt;false&lt;/convertibleToPdf&gt;
  &lt;convertibleToSwf&gt;false&lt;/convertibleToSwf&gt;
  &lt;convertibleToDxf&gt;false&lt;/convertibleToDxf&gt;
  &lt;created&gt;01/01/0001 0:00:00&lt;/created&gt;
  &lt;path&gt;/okm:root/myDoc.doc&lt;/path&gt;
  &lt;permissions&gt;0&lt;/permissions&gt;
  &lt;subscribed&gt;false&lt;/subscribed&gt;
&lt;/document&gt;
-------------------------------28947758029299
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="myDoc.doc"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

;

Seems the differences is I'm not indicating that the content is application/xml ( **Content-Type: application/xml** ? )

This is my code, any suggestion is wellcome

```
IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(uriHelper.DOCUMENT_CREATE, Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
Document testdoc = new Document();
testdoc.path = "/okm:root/myDoc.doc";
string doc = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" + request.XmlSerializer.Serialize (testdoc).Replace("<Document>", "<document>").Replace("</Document>", "</document>");
request.AddParameter("doc", doc);

byte[] bytes = beanHelper.ReadToEnd(fileStream);
String fileName = Path.GetFileName(docPath);
request.AddFile("content", bytes, fileName);

RestClient client = getClient(url, user, password);
IRestResponse<Document> response = client.Execute<Document>(request);
```